# Animate a lens flare in Unity when the Camera is not moving

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem to animate a lens flare when the camera is not moving. I would like to achieve the following effect : The light is behind a sphere, and the lens flare associated to the light should rotate without a camera movement. 
Right now, I need to move the camera if I want the flare to animate itself.[Actual Flare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxCaz.png) You can also see that if the flare is behind the sphere the source point is not hidden by the object.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional lens flares don't rotate.
Watch [this](http://youtube.com/watch?v=BeTI5hbOIAU) video.

As you can see, the prominent flare line stays at the same angle relative to the screen, even when he rotates the camera.
The rotation effects you might see are actually new flares appearing and disappearing as he rotates the camera, rolling off the camera lens' curved surface.

Rotating the flares would be irrealistic.  If the camera and lightsource doesn't change position, then the lens flare shouldn't change.  But with a little research a few great-looking, cinematic quality flare packs can be found  on the asset store(like [Easy Flares pro](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/30524) or [ProFlares](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/12845)).